# LXML element tree removal based on list using Python 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

Using LXML, I am looking to open an existing XML file, remove some `<device>` element trees based on a match made from a list of devices and save the edited XML under the same file name.

Here's the existing XML content:

```
<testsetup>
    <devices>
      <device>
        <name>DEVICE1</name>
        <id>SomeID</id>
        <keyitem>
          <file1>/some/file/path</file1>
          <file2>/some/file/path</file2>
        </keyitem>
      </device>
      <device>
        <name>DEVICE2</name>
        <id>SomeID</id>
        <keyitem>
          <file1>/some/file/path</file1>
          <file2>/some/file/path</file2>
        </keyitem>
      </device>
      <device>
        <name>DEVICE3</name>
        <id>SomeID</id>
        <keyitem>
          <file1>/some/file/path</file1>
          <file2>/some/file/path</file2>
        </keyitem>
      </device>
      <device>
        <name>DEVICE4</name>
        <id>SomeID</id>
        <keyitem>
          <file1>/some/file/path</file1>
          <file2>/some/file/path</file2>
        </keyitem>
      </device>
    </devices>
</testsetup>
```

I have a list of devices I need to remove:

```
remove_items = ['DEVICE1', 'DEVICE3']
```

I am looking to get to the following pretty printed in the output file:

```
<testsetup>
   <devices>
      <device>
        <name>DEVICE2</name>
        <id>SomeID</id>
        <keyitem>
          <file1>/some/file/path</file1>
          <file2>/some/file/path</file2>
        </keyitem>
      </device>
      <device>
        <name>DEVICE4</name>
        <id>SomeID</id>
        <keyitem>
          <file1>/some/file/path</file1>
          <file2>/some/file/path</file2>
        </keyitem>
      </device>
   </devices>
</testsetup>
```

I have made a muddled attempt below:

```
import lxml.etree as et

remove_items = ['DEVICE1', 'DEVICE3']

with open('somefile.xml', 'w+', newline='') as out_file:
    root = et.parse(out_file)

    for dev in remove_items:
        for elem in root.xpath(".//device/@name='"+dev+"'"):
            elem.getparent().remove(elem)
```

But I'm probably going along the wrong route. How can I properly do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, there are few things you need to do to make your code work:

1. Open the file as `read` (`'r'`) and store it's content before you open it for writing (`'w+'`)
2. To select the `<device>` that has a `<name>` which equals `'DEVICE1'`, use this xpath: `.//device[name='DEVICE1']`
3. Once you're done processing the tree, use `lxml.etree.tostring` on the root to get the XML string equivalent of your tree.

Here's a working solution after applying the above modifications:

```
from lxml.etree import parse, tostring

remove_items = ['DEVICE1', 'DEVICE3']
file_name = 'somefile.xml'

with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
    root = parse(in_file)

for dev in remove_items:
    for elem in root.xpath(".//device[name='" + dev + "']"):
        elem.getparent().remove(elem)

with open(file_name, 'w+') as out_file:
    out_file.write(tostring(root).decode())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked, much appreciated.  This may lead me on to another question soon.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be:

```
import lxml.etree as et

remove_items = ['DEVICE1', 'DEVICE3']


with open('test1.xml', 'r') as reader, open('test2.xml', 'w') as writer:
    tree = et.parse(reader)
    devices = tree.getroot().find('devices')

    for element in devices.iter('device'):

        if element.findtext('name') in remove_items:
            print(element.findtext('name'))
            devices.remove(element)

    writer.write(et.tostring(devices, pretty_print = True).decode('utf-8'))
```